# VideoJs Button Skip Ad do not hide on click

Tags: jquery, video, video.js

I use VideoJs player for my project. I have ads for preload, but do not delay minutes for "Skip Ad" button and when i click it the button do not show. I tried with function of player, but nothing happend and i tried to catch click on button with jquery but do not catch the click. Where i am wrong?

```
  <video style="width: 100%; height: 550px;"  id="videobigmain" poster="<?=\backend\models\Page::getMainPoster(68)?>" class="video video-js vjs-default-skin" controls  data-setup="{}" >
      <source src="<?=\backend\models\Page::getVideo(68,1)?>" type="video/mp4">
//this is not work
      <div class="videojs-ads-info enabled">
          <span>Your video will resume in 23 seconds</span>
          <a class="enabled">Skip Ad</a>
      </div>
 </video>
```

and script:

```
  videojs('#videobigmain', {}, function () {
          var player = this;
//custom button for share the video
          var VjsButton = videojs.getComponent("Button");
          var customButton = videojs.extend(VjsButton, {
                constructor: function(player, options){
                            VjsButton.call(this, player, options);
                            this.controlText("Get Code Iframe");
                            },
                handleClick: function() {
                        $(".popup, .popup-content").addClass("active settings-popup");
                },
                buildCSSClass: function() {
                        return "vjs-icon-custombutton vjs-control vjs-button";
                            }
                });
                videojs.registerComponent("customButton", customButton);                                         player.getChild("controlBar").addChild("customButton", {});
                <?php if(\backend\models\Page::hasAds(68,1) == true){ ?>
                                                player.ads();
                                                player.skipAds({
                                                    delayInSeconds: 10
                                                });
                                                player.on('contentchanged', function () {
                                                    player.trigger('adsready');
                                                });
                                                player.on('readyforpreroll', function () {
                player.ads.startLinearAdMode();
                player.src("<?=\backend\models\Page::getAds(68,1)?>");
                player.one('adplaying', function () {
                        player.trigger('ads-ad-started');
                });
                player.one('adended', function () {
                        player.ads.endLinearAdMode();
                        $(".videojs-ads-info").css("display", "none");
                        });
                });
                <?php } ?>
                player.trigger('adsready');
         });
        $( "#close-p" ).on( "click", function() {
       $(".popup, .popup-content").removeClass("active settings-popup");                                       });
       $( ".videojs-ads-info" ).on( "click", function() {
          $(".videojs-ads-info").css("display", "none");
       });
       $( ".videojs-ads-info > a" ).on( "click", function() {
          $(".videojs-ads-info").css("display", "none");
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 videojs-ads-info block on the page:

- static item you inserted, but it's hidden and useless
- dynamic item js inserted and working.

Change that:

```
$( ".videojs-ads-info" ).on( "click", function() {
  $(".videojs-ads-info").css("display", "none");
});
$( ".videojs-ads-info > a" ).on( "click", function() {
  $(".videojs-ads-info").css("display", "none");
});
```

To this:

```
$('#videobigmain').on('click', '.videojs-ads-info a', function () {
  $(".videojs-ads-info").css("display", "none");
});
```